# makes BelongsTo dropdown options dependit on the first one

Tags: laravel-nova

I have sections belons to classes so when I chosse one class it should only shows related classes

I've tried using laravel nova package but it doesn't work so so i want to do it manualy

Answer (score 0):

which packages did you test? have you test this one?
[nova-belongsto-depend](https://github.com/orlyapps/nova-belongsto-depend)